# Define touchable area on a scaled image in android

Tags: android, graphics, android-imageview

I have asked questions related to this before, but I think I was framing my objective incorrectly.

What I have: a custom ImageView that displays a graphic and defines multiple touchable areas as rectangles within the image.  My problem is scaling.  I want to define the touchable area of the image based on it's actual resolution in the bitmap file, but translate those coordinates so the the rectangle covers the same area on the scaled image.

This is what I've got so far:
When the view is created, calculate the ratio of the actual to scaled sizes

```
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
Drawable pic=this.getDrawable();
int realHeight= pic.getIntrinsicHeight();   
int realWidth=pic.getIntrinsicWidth();
int scaledHeight=this.getHeight();
int scaleWidth=this.getWidth();
heightRatio=(float)realHeight/scaledHeight;
widthRatio=(float)realWidth/scaleWidth;
}
```

Now I want to take the coordinates that define rectangle(s) on the original (un-scaled) image 
and draw that rectangle(s) to the same area of the image -- but accounting for scale:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
super.onDraw(canvas);
Paint p=new Paint();
p.setStrokeWidth(1);
p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
for (HotSpot h: spots)
{
//Each hotspot has a rectangle defined in reference to the actual size of the image
Rect old=h.getRect();
float offsetLeft=old.left+(old.left*widthRatio);
float offsetTop=old.top+(old.top*heightRatio);
float offsetRight=old.right+(old.right*heightRatio);
float offsetBottom=old.bottom+(old.bottom*widthRatio);
RectF nRect=new RectF(offsetLeft,offsetTop,offsetRight,offsetBottom);
canvas.drawRect(nRect,p);

 }
```

The results are "in the ball park" but not quite accurate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution:

- Get the screen density
- Get the image height (or width)
- Divide the height (or width) by the density, so you get the length in inches
- Divide the coordinate by the length in inches, so you get a relationship between the coordinate and the image which is independent by the image effective size
- When you have to draw the same point on a differently scaled image, multiply the last result for the length in inches of the second image (which you obtain using the same operations listed above)

Example:
On the first image:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = getWidth();
float inchesLength = width/density;
float scaledXCenter = xCenter / inchesLength;
```

On the same image with a different scale:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int width = getWidth();
float inchesLength = width/density;
float restoredXCenter = scaledXCenter * inchesLength;
```